# Get file path from URI on Android 10,

Tags: android, filepicker, android-10.0

I need to pick files from the device,

Here is my code,

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
```

The picked URIs url always like this on Android 10 devices,

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:75878
```

I tried many different solutions to get the file path from this URI but with no luck,

Note: my app works perfectly on pre-Android 10 devices and I am able to get the picked files paths.

Comment: using paths is deprecated for a long time, it was finally disabled in android 10

Comment: Did you find answer for this.. I am also struggling to get that on Android 10.

Comment: @SwapnilKale on Android 10 no paths are deprecated, instead, use the picked file URI, intent.getData()

Comment: This question is also interesting for apps the acts like files manager. I couldn't think of a way to retrieve files paths. =/

Comment: What is the solution for this issue

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63032934/12401637

Comment: @gowtham6672 Link doesn't work :(

Comment: @Scalway https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085035/12401637