# How to get the path of a video which is selected from gallery on android 10

Tags: java, android, path, android-contentresolver

I tried lot of snippets. This is what I'm using now. I know that MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA is deprecated.somehow this method is working on android 10 as well but sometimes it throws

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

```
public static String getvideoPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        LogMessage.v("Document Id:: "+document_id);
        if(document_id!=null){
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;
        }else
            return getPath(context,uri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return getPath(context,uri);
    }
}

private static String getPath(Context context,Uri uri){
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        return document_id;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Get real path of video selected from gallery with below method

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public  String getPath( final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat ) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider

       if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
            if (fullPath != "") {
                return fullPath;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }


        // DownloadsProvider

        if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                final String id;
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                            return path;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
                id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                            "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                            "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                    };
                    for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                        try {
                            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));


                            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                            return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            else {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                try {
                    contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (contentUri != null) {

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
            }
        }


        // MediaProvider
       if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;

            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }

       if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
            return getDriveFilePath(uri);
        }

       if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
            return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
        }


       if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri);
            }
            if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            {

                // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                return copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"userfiles");
                // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
            }
            else
            {
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }

       }
       if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }
    else {

        if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
            return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
        }

        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }




    return null;
}

private  boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);

    return file.exists();
}

private String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
    final String type = pathData[0];
    final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
    String fullPath = "";

    // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
    // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
    // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
    //
    // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
        fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }
    }

    // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
    // so we cannot relay on it.
    //
    // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
    // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
    fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
    if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
        return fullPath;
    }

    fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
    if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
        return fullPath;
    }

    return fullPath;
}

private String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;
    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
    File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

        //int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return file.getPath();
}

/***
 * Used for Android Q+
 * @param uri
 * @param newDirName if you want to create a directory, you can set this variable
 * @return
 */
private String copyFileToInternalStorage(Uri uri,String newDirName) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;

    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, new String[]{
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,OpenableColumns.SIZE
    }, null, null, null);


    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

    File output;
    if(!newDirName.equals("")) {
        File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name);
    }
    else{
        output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
    }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        int read = 0;
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }

    return output.getPath();
}

private String getFilePathForWhatsApp(Uri uri){
        return  copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"whatsapp");
}

private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return null;
}

private  boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private  boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private  boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private  boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public boolean isWhatsAppFile(Uri uri){
    return "com.whatsapp.provider.media".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private  boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome and detailed answer! Maybe I've missed something here but how can this be modified to get the **path/uri** of the **thumbnails** for the videos? The new `loadThumbnail` method doesn't actually provide a uri to the thumbnail file.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer which is given by tushar is abosulity correct, I have converted that code into kotlin, might be it helps someone.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.provider.OpenableColumns
import android.text.TextUtils
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import kotlin.math.min


@SuppressLint("Recycle")
@Suppress("RECEIVER_NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS", "DEPRECATION")
object FileManager {
    
    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
        var selection: String? = null
        var selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                //val type = split[0]
                val fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split)
                return if (fullPath !== "") {
                    fullPath
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }


            // DownloadsProvider
            if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    var cursor: Cursor? = null
                    try {
                        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            val fileName: String = cursor.getString(0)
                            val path: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor?.close()
                    }
                    val id: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                        }
                        val contentUriPrefixesToTry = arrayOf("content://downloads/public_downloads", "content://downloads/my_downloads")
                        for (contentUriPrefix in contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            return try {
                                val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                                getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                uri.path?.replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "")?.replaceFirst("^raw:", "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                    }
                    var contentUri : Uri?= null
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                    }
                }
            }


            // MediaProvider
            if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                when (type) {
                    "image" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                    "video" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                    "audio" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                }
                selection = "_id=?"
                selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri!!, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(context,uri)
            }
            if (isWhatsAppFile(uri)) {
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(context, uri)
            }
            if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
                if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                    return uri.lastPathSegment
                }
                if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                    return getDriveFilePath(context, uri)
                }
                return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

                    // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                    copyFileToInternalStorage(context, uri, "userfiles")
                    // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
                } else {
                    getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
                }
            }
            if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return uri.path
            }
        } else {
            if (isWhatsAppFile(uri)) {
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(context, uri)
            }
            if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
                val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val cursor: Cursor
                try {
                    cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)!!
                    val columnIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun fileExists(filePath: String): Boolean {
        val file = File(filePath)
        return file.exists()
    }

    private fun getPathFromExtSD(pathData: Array<String>): String {
        val type = pathData[0]
        val relativePath = "/" + pathData[1]
        var fullPath : String

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + relativePath
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath
        }
        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath
        return if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            fullPath
        } else fullPath
    }
    
    private fun getDriveFilePath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val returnUri: Uri = uri
        val returnCursor: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)!!
        /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
        val nameIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
       // val sizeIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        val name: String = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
       // val size = returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
        val file = File(context.cacheDir, name)
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            var read : Int
            val maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024
            val bytesAvailable: Int = inputStream?.available()!!

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            val bufferSize = min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize)
            val buffers = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            while (inputStream.read(buffers).also { read = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
            }
            Timber.d("File Size Size ${file.length()}")
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()
            Timber.d("File Path Path ${file.path}")
            Timber.d("File Size Size ${file.length()}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("Exception ${e.message}")
        }
        return file.path
    }

    /***
     * Used for Android Q+
     * @param uri
     * @param newDirName if you want to create a directory, you can set this variable
     * @return
     */
    private fun copyFileToInternalStorage(context: Context, uri: Uri, newDirName: String): String? {
        val returnUri: Uri = uri
        val returnCursor: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(returnUri, arrayOf(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE), null, null, null)!!


        /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
        val nameIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        //val sizeIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        val name: String = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
       // val size = returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
        val output: File = if (newDirName != "") {
            val dir = File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName)
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir()
            }
            File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name)
        } else {
            File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + name)
        }
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(output)
            var read = 0
            val bufferSize = 1024
            val buffers = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            while (inputStream?.read(buffers).also {
                    if (it != null) {
                        read = it
                    }
                } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
            }
            inputStream?.close()
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("Exception${e.message}")
        }
        return output.path
    }

    private fun getFilePathForWhatsApp(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        return copyFileToInternalStorage(context, uri, "whatsapp")
    }

    private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isWhatsAppFile(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.whatsapp.provider.media" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isGoogleDriveUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage" == uri.authority || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy" == uri.authority
    }

}
```

To launch

```
 val intent = Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.apply {
                type = "application/pdf"
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            }
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

and you can get the result in your acivity

```
 private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        var file: File? = null
        val disposable = Single.fromCallable {
            val filePath = FileManager.getPath(this, result?.data?.data!!)
            file = File(filePath)
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({
            Timber.d("==File==Path===${file?.path}\nname==${file?.name}\nabsolutePath =${file?.absolutePath}")

        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
        })


    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You will not try yo convert an uri to a file system path in Android 10.

Even if you manage the path is mostly not accessable.

You are not a regular reader of stackoverflow pages are you?